# Pandas getting error while converting all dates to start date of week

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the date to week period and then get first part of periods.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)
```

but it's giving me an error

```
AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'start_time'
```

I am using pandas 0.25.2 version.

though it was running previously but not running this time. can't able to identify what happend. Please help with the error

Comment: Your data has missing values that are (in case of datetime objects) represented as `NaT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trick `np.nan != np.nan`, so you can add `if-else` statement or use [`Series.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) with default `how='s'`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date (mm/dd/yyyy)': rng})  
df.loc[0, 'Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'] = np.nan

df['Date'] = (df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.to_period('W')
                                     .apply(lambda r: r.start_time if r == r else np.nan))

df['Date1'] = df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.to_period('W').dt.to_timestamp()

print (df)
  Date (mm/dd/yyyy)       Date      Date1
0               NaT        NaT        NaT
1        2017-04-04 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
2        2017-04-05 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
3        2017-04-06 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
4        2017-04-07 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
5        2017-04-08 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
6        2017-04-09 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
7        2017-04-10 2017-04-10 2017-04-10
8        2017-04-11 2017-04-10 2017-04-10
9        2017-04-12 2017-04-10 2017-04-10
```